# Does jQuery continue filtering if it finds 0 matches?

Tags: jquery

I have a question regarding efficiency of jQuery filtering. I've just written quite a lengthy expression and I was wondering if jQuery stops filtering if the current number of matches is 0.

```
passengers.filter('input.FromDate[value="01/09/2011"]')
          .closest('tr')
          .filter('input.ToDate[value="08/09/2011"]')
          .length;
```

If after the first `filter()` call the number of matches is 0 will jQuery continue to search the DOM or will it forego the additional calls and just return 0?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The nice thing about chainable calls with jQuery is that when there are no matches, nothing bad will happen.

When you call `.filter` and zero matches have been yielded, you *are* executing the subsequently chained method calls by definition because they are invoked directly on the returned object (that's what chaining is).

When there are no matches, JavaScript will still invoke each subsequently chained method on each returned object. How much wasted processing happens depends on how the specific method has been implemented.

```
$.fn.doesItTryToDoStuff = function() {
    alert('called');

    // here I could have some wasteful process
    // which could foolishly be executed
    // even when there are no elements


    return this.each(function() {
       $(this).css("border", "1px solid red"); 
    });
};

$("input").filter("[value='foo']").doesItTryToDoStuff().doesItTryToDoStuff();
```

[Demo.](http://jsfiddle.net/karim79/k6Pw9/3/)

I would expect that most jQuery methods are coded such that nothing drastic happens before the length of the collection has been tested, but you never know.

Comment: Marking this as the accepted answer as it addresses efficiency which is what my question was actually about.

Answer (score 3):

Filtering on something that doesn't exist is going to return an empty wrapped set. Subsequent filters will be called but won't have any effect.

```
$('div').filter('.isnt-here').end().filter('.spacer').length;
```

Running this on the question page returns `25`.

Comment: So would it be more efficient to leave the expression as it is or separate out the filter() calls and check the length after each call?

Comment: `filter` uses `grep` internally. You can look at the source here, [`filter`](http://james.padolsey.com/jquery/#v=1.6.2&fn=jQuery.fn.filter) and [`grep`](http://james.padolsey.com/jquery/#v=1.6.2&fn=jQuery.grep). I wont be too worried about having a couple of filters extra unless I have identified it as a bottleneck in my application.

Answer (score 0):

Filtering in jQuery will return a jQuery object with DOM list of matched elements, the subsequent filter will be called on those DOM elements, and so on.

If there are no matches, filtering in jQuery will return a jQuery object with empty DOM list and call the subsequent filter for the empty list, so it will return no match as well.

It is like narrowing the filter scope.